# Nested Object Transformation using Stream API Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a Class like this to store APIResponse from REST-API call

```
class DataSet {
        public String ID;    
        List<DataPoint> dataPoints;
}

class DataPoint{
       DateTime timeStamp;
       Double value;
}
```

What I have is an ArrayList of DataSet and need to transform into something like this

```
[{x: timestamp1, y: value1}, {x: timestamp2, y: value2},... {x: timestampn, y: valuen}]
```

for each element in the ArrayList.

I am learning Stream API of Java 8 and wish to do it using the same.
Would like to know how to arrive at the output using lambda expressions of Stream API java 8.

Currently the desired output is being acheived by traditional way of using for-each which is:

```
List<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>> transformedObject = new List<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>();
        for(DataSet m : apiResponseArray){  
            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> dataobj = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();      
            List<DataPoint> listData =m.getdataPoints();
            for(DataPoint d : listData)
            {
                Map<String, Object> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();                  
                dataMap.put("x", d.getTime(););
                dataMap.put("y", d.getValue());
                dataobj.add(dataMap);
            }
            transformedObject.add(dataobj);         
        }
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(transformedObject);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You could flat map `apiResponseArray`, but I doubt it'll improve your code significantly.

Comment: @shmosel how can i make the stream to return a list of arraylists of maps that way?

Comment: @shmosel what else would u suggest to improve performance here?

Comment: Was there a performance issue? You didn't mention any.

Comment: @shmosel Yes its taking quite a bit of time for the conversion.Since the response is huge, i thought using streams might help.
Pardon me if my thinking isnt right.

Comment: Did you verify that the bottleneck is in the loop and not in the serialization afterwards?

Comment: @shmosel Yes , i tried with Different libraries for serialization, and was able to improve little bit. hoping to squeeze as much as improvement

Comment: Your code produces a list of list of map, but your sample output only shows a list of map. Which do you want?

Comment: Actually I have mentioned that the output is for each element in the array list, so **List of list of maps** is what is required @shmosel

Comment: There seems to be a performance improvement while usings streams against my expectation. Do you think it is better to post that as a separate question? or is it something that is not unusual? @shmosel

Comment: If it's not parallel, that's a bit surprising. I would only post a new question if you can produce a [mcve] demonstrating the performance difference.

Comment: Would love to do the same :)

Comment: I am posting a new question with performance measures  ;), so will be sharing the link in the comments @shmosel . take a look at it if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way with inner stream (if you really want list of list of map :) )

```
private Map<String, Object> map(DataPoint dataPoint) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("x", dataPoint.timeStamp);
    map.put("y", dataPoint.value);
    return map;
}


List<List<Map<String, Object>>> transformedObject = dataSets.stream()
            .map(
                    dataSet -> dataSet.dataPoints.stream()
                        .map(this::map)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what is your take on the performance improvement through this approach, as opposed to the traditional approach?

Comment: @BabyHulk There is no performance impact, but you did not mention it in your original question. You wanted to rewrite it to streams, only.

Comment: Probably, the loop is not bottleneck, but serialization itself as @shmosel wrote. Of course you can use parallel streams, but I have doubts about improving performance in your case.

Comment: But Interestingly though certainly not expected, streams is giving some kind of perfomance improvement when tested. Searching for a proper explanation to which it can be attributed to. @rejthy